# How can I access Ubuntu Server running in a VM via the internet?

Tags: server, virtualbox, virtualization

I am running Ubuntu Server 10.04 on a VirtualBox virtual machine from a Windows 7 host.

How do I open access to this guest virtual machine from the internet?

Answer (score 2):

U can access your vm anywhere by " D D N S " link  (what it does give u static link and make your dynamic ip auto updated through DDNS link )

Example link would like this **xxx.no-ip.org**

register  www.no-ip.com

> most of router support ddns u can login your ddns id
>   [image]

now u need to DMZ to the ip of vm 
[image]

NOW OPEN VIRTUAL BOX > CLICK ON VM > SETTINGS > NETWORK [image]

**NOW USE STATIC IP AS I HAVE DMZ TO IP 192.168.0.200 SO MY VM IP SHOULD BE 192.168.0.200**

> Install any service in your vm , like Apache , Ssh
>
> now u can ssh anywhere from like this `**ssh user-name@xxx.no-ip.org**`
>
> if your have apache installed on vm just paste link `xxx.no-ip.org` on web browser it will open your web from your vm

There are Lots Of DDNS Services , But U Need To Check Which One Your Router Support 
By DDNS > Service Provider