# Is it possible to use Ubuntu as a Broadband Remote Access Server?

Tags: networking, server

I want to know if it is possible to use an Ubuntu server as BRAS (Broadband Remote Access Server), pppoe-server, in network - if so how many concurrent users could it support?

Comment: assuming BRAS = Broadband Remote Access Server. Please update question it you are talking about something else (like the womens garments :) )

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100550/how-can-i-access-ubuntu-server-running-in-a-vm-via-the-internet/100561#100561

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use Ubuntu as a Broadband Remote Access Server. You are limited only by system resources (ie, amount of memory, 32- vs 64-bit). There are no artificial limits imposed by licensing.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the important point is how can we use is it? could you please refer me to a how-to document?

Comment: @Amir Ah, *that* is an entirely different, and good, question. Please edit your question to ask what you intended. Alas, I don't have the answer for that, but someone else might.